# TDMA with 3rd order upwind scheme

Tags: linear-algebra, finite-volume, linear-system, banded-matrix

I'm trying to implement a model I found in a paper, but there is something I do not understand. The authors say they use TDMA to solve their equations; however, they use a 3rd order upwind biased approximation to discretize the convective terms. This leads to an almost tridiagonal matrix (with coeff. for the terms $i-1$, $i$, and $i+1$), but with an extra diagonal line for the $i-2$ terms.

Is it possible to use a TDMA solver with a matrix like this? Is there some procedure to tridiagolise?

Comment: what paper are you referring to, exactly?

Comment: Can you write what the structure of the matrix looks like? And the equations that you’re solving?

Answer (score 1):

I would assume, that your $N\times N$ system has the following form:

$$
\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}
b_1 & c_1 &     &     &     &   0     \\
a_1 & b_2 & c_2 &     &     &           \\
s_1 & a_2 & b_3 & c_3 &     &           \\
    & s_2 & a_3 & b_4 & \ddots &           \\
    &     & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & c_{N-1}\\
0   &     &        & s_{N-2} & a_{N-1} & b_N
\end{pmatrix}}_{M}
\begin{pmatrix}
x_1\\
x_2\\
x_3\\
x_4\\
\vdots\\
x_{N}
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
d_1\\
d_2\\
d_3\\
d_4\\
\vdots\\
d_{N}
\end{pmatrix}
\tag{1}
\label{fourDiagSystem}
$$
So, our matrix $M$ is a four-diagonal matrix (lower bandwidth = 2, upper bandwidth = 1), where $\{s_1,\ldots,s_{N-2} \}$ is the "additional" (to the classic triadiagonal case) lower diagonal.

So, if all $s_i$ are zeroes, this matrix can be solved using the classical tridiagonal algorithm (Thomas).
There are several ways to look at this problem:

1. Explicitly derive the expressions for this four-diagonal case, similar to the derivation of the Thomas algorithm.
2. The derivation in the previous "approach" can go along Crout's method. For example, see [Numerical Recepies](http://www.aip.de/groups/soe/local/numres/bookfpdf/f2-3.pdf) (Sections 2.3, 2.4).
3. Use block-tridiagonal algorithm (Thomas algorithm for block matrices) with block size of $2\times 2$.

Since the question asks directly about using Thomas algorithm, I would go only into the **third point**.

Assume (without loss of generality) $N$ being even. Then, $M$ from $\eqref{fourDiagSystem}$ can be rewritten, as follows:
$$
M=\begin{pmatrix}
\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix} b_1 & c_1 \\ a_1 & b_2 \end{pmatrix}}_{B_{1}} &
\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ c_2 & 0\end{pmatrix}}_{C_{1}} & 
&
\\
\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix} s_1 & a_2 \\ 0 & s_2 \end{pmatrix}}_{A_{1}} &
\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix} b_3 & c_3 \\ a_3 & b_4 \end{pmatrix}}_{B_{2}} &
\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ c_4 & 0\end{pmatrix}}_{C_{2}} &
\\
&
\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix} s_3 & a_4 \\ 0 & s_4 \end{pmatrix}}_{A_{2}} &
\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix} b_5 & c_5 \\ a_5 & b_6 \end{pmatrix}}_{B_{2}} &
\ddots
\\
&
\ddots &
\ddots &
\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0\\
c_{N-2} & 0
\end{pmatrix}}_{C_{N/2-1}}
\\
&
&
\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}
s_{N-3} & a_{N-2}\\
0 & s_{N-2}
\end{pmatrix}}_{A_{N/2-1}}
&
\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}
b_{N-1} & c_{N-1}\\
a_{N-1} & b_{N}
\end{pmatrix}}_{B_{N/2}}
\end{pmatrix}
$$

or, removing the clarifying annotations, $\eqref{fourDiagSystem}$ becomes:

$$
\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}
B_1 & C_1 & & &0\\
A_1 & B_2 & C_2 &\\
    & A_2 & B_3 & \ddots &\\
   &     & \ddots & \ddots & C_{N/2-1}\\
0 & & & A_{N/2-1} & B_{N/2}
\end{pmatrix}}_{M_\text{block}}
\begin{pmatrix}
Y_1\\
Y_2\\
Y_3\\
\vdots\\
Y_{N/2}
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
D_1\\
D_2\\
D_3\\
\vdots\\
D_{N/2}
\end{pmatrix}
\tag{2}
\label{triBlockDiagSystem}
$$

Now, in $\eqref{triBlockDiagSystem}$, $M_\text{block}$ is simply a $2\times 2$ block representation of $M$ in $\eqref{fourDiagSystem}$.
$$
B_i=\begin{pmatrix}
b_{2i-1} & c_{2i-1}\\
a_{2i-1} & b_{2i}
\end{pmatrix},\quad 
A_j=\begin{pmatrix}
s_{2j-1} & a_{2j}\\
0 & s_{2j}
\end{pmatrix},\quad
C_j=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0\\
c_{2j} & 0
\end{pmatrix},\\
i=1,\ldots,\frac{N}{2},\quad j=1,\ldots,\frac{N}{2}-1
$$

Now, you can apply the block-Thomas algorithm to the $\eqref{triBlockDiagSystem}$, in which you can also **take advantage of the special structure** of your $C_j$ and $A_j$ blocks.

For the details on block-Thomas, you can refer to [Chapter 2.5](http://www4.ncsu.edu/eos/users/w/white/www/white/ma580/chap2.5.PDF) of [MA/CSC 580:  Numerical Analysis I course by R. E. White from North Carolina](http://www4.ncsu.edu/eos/users/w/white/www/white/ma580/ma580hp.htm), but they are effictively standard non-blocked Thomas where operations with scalars are changed to their counterparts with matrices (*scalar-scalar* product and *scalar division* become *matrix-matrix* product and *inverse*, or, more stable *small*, $2\times 2$ in your case, *system solve*).

Also, see the discussion in [this related CompSci question on block-tridiagonal algorithm](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/6701/20688).